# Property undefined Angular2 and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, angular, undefined

I am trying to retrieve the contents of a local json file through the use of the Angular2 module Http.

The error I am getting is of an undefined property but I reckon it should have been initialized when the prepareCredentials function is called onComplete by the Observable/Subscribe.

Here follows the Error,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientId' of undefined
    at SpotifyComponent.prepareCredentials (spotify.component.ts:58)
    at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _complete] (spotify.component.ts:38)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.ts:240)
    at SafeSubscriber.complete (Subscriber.ts:226)
    at Subscriber._complete (Subscriber.ts:142)
    at Subscriber.complete (Subscriber.ts:120)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._complete (Subscriber.ts:142)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (Subscriber.ts:120)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (xhr_backend.ts:67)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:356)
```

Component,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { SpotifyService } from './spotify.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-spotify',
  templateUrl: 'spotify.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['spotify.component.css'],
  providers: [SpotifyService]
})

export class SpotifyComponent implements OnInit {
  private credentialsData: {
    clientId: string,
    clientSecret: string
  };

  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private spotifyService: SpotifyService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.spotifyService) {
      this.http.get('../app/data/credentials.json')
        .map(this.handleResponse)
        .subscribe(
          this.setupCredentials,
          this.handleError,
          () => { this.prepareCredentials(); }
        );
    }
  }

  private setupCredentials(subData) {
    console.log('Setting up credentials...');
    this.credentialsData = {
      clientId: <string>subData.clientId,
      clientSecret: <string>subData.clientSecret
    };
    console.log('credentials: ' +
        JSON.stringify(this.credentialsData));
    console.log('credentials clientId: ' +  this.credentialsData.clientId);
    console.log('credentials clientSecret: ' + this.credentialsData.clientSecret);
  }

  private prepareCredentials() {
    console.log('Preparing credentials...');
    this.spotifyService.prepare(
      this.credentialsData.clientId,
      this.credentialsData.clientSecret,
      '', 'http://localhost:4200/spotify');

  }

  private handleResponse(res: Response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res.json()));
    return res.json().spotify;
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server     error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }

}
```

and the Service,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SpotifyService {
  private clientId: string;
  private clientSecret: string;
  private scopes: string;
  private callbackUrl: string;

  constructor() { }

  wakeUpTest(): string {
    console.log('SpotifyService is awake and initiated.');
    return 'SpotifyService is awake and initiated.';
  }

  prepare(clientId: string,
    clientSecret: string,
    scopes: string,
    callbackUrl: string): void {
        console.log(clientId);
  }

  getAuthCode(): void {
    let authUrl: string = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize' +
      '?response_type=code' +
      '&client_id=' + this.clientId +
      '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(this.scopes) +
      '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(this.callbackUrl);
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or pointers as all this is relatively new for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that your problem is located here:

```
this.http.get('../app/data/credentials.json')
  .map(this.handleResponse)
  .subscribe(
    this.setupCredentials,  <== 
    this.handleError,
    () => { this.prepareCredentials(); }
  );
```

That's default JS/TS behavior if you pass a method reference directly. You can either use bind like `this.setupCredentials.bind(this)` or use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this) to retain `this`:

```
this.http.get('../app/data/credentials.json')
   .map(this.handleResponse)
   .subscribe(
      (data) => this.setupCredentials(data),
      (res) => this.handleError(res),
      () => { this.prepareCredentials(); }
   );
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: This is being done implicitly I would assume as I am gretting all the printouts in setupCredentials? It is also the same practice done in the angular documentation, passing merely the function for an implicit data pass.

Comment: Try print `this` before `console.log('Setting up credentials...');`

Comment: Printing `this` gave me a printout of a `SafeSubscriber` object, [like so](http://pastebin.com/M4GDSZv1).

Comment: I am going to have to excuse myself, the solution you provided actually solved my problem. Does this have to do with instantiation of objects? And is my case a special case, due to the Angular2 documentation doing it the way I did it at first? Anyways, thanks for the help @yurzui.

Comment: Can i see the link to an example of the documentation where is used this practice?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#fetch-data It does seem that I got map and subscribe mixed up though, as it seems to be a possible practice in a map.

Comment: Just they don't use `this` keywords(`MapSubscriber` in this way) in `map` callbacks. .